Missing assembly reference of a ProjectReference after dotnet upgrade 4.8
I know that there are many threads on this but I tried all possible solutions without any success.
I have a solution with multiple projects. Project A has a reference to project B. In my A.csproj:
<ProjectReference Include="..\B\B.csproj">
      <Project>{795b8266-e62c-4d04-b8eb-cfrf5a31f55x}</Project>
      <Name>B</Name>
</ProjectReference>

I recently upgraded both projects Target framework from .Net Framework 4.6.1 to .Net Framework 4.8. After the upgrade, when I build project B in VS it builds succesfully, but when I build project A I get lots of errors of type code CS0246 The type or namespace name 'B' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
The strange thing is that when I build the solution from the VS developer command prompt using MSBuild solution.sln I get no errors, furthermore, if I change the reference from "ProjectReference" to a regular reference to the dll (browsing it), that error disappear.
<Reference Include="B, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\B\bin\Release\B.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

I want to be able to build the solution straight from the UI and not from the CMD, and I don't want to make changes to the references as I have lots more references with same errors and I'm not quite sure if that's a good idea to change projectreference to browsed reference.
What I tried to do:

Made sure that there's no .NET Target Framework mismatch, both projects A and B and others uses .NET 4.8
Ran Update-Package –reinstall in Nuget Package Manager CMD
Removed the reference and added it back
Cleaned solution and Build again
Unloaded both projects and reloaded them
Restarted VS in admin mode
Delete the project and reclone it
Retarget solution to different Windows SDK versions
Checked build order and insured that project B is built before project A
Deleted %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\2019\ComponentModelCache

I'm building in Release, Mixed Platforms mode

Maybe something worth trying : Set a version on your projects ( for instance 1.1.0.0 instead of 1.0.0.0), change the reference to B accordingly, and even try to set the "SpecificVersion" Tag to True

I find it strange that the hint path includes the "Release" folder. What happens if you build in Debug configuration?

@Pac0 I tried to change assymbly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.0") and assymbly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.0.0") in AssemblyInfo.cs file for both projects, also added <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion> under the PrjectReference tag, didn't help :(

@Pac0 Even if I build in Debug mode, I don't get the error when adding a browsed reference

After reviewing changes done to A.csproj after dotnet upgrade, I see change in this block:
Before:
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion>10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />

After:
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />

The 3 conditions in the tags that was eliminated after the dotnet upgrade for some reason caused for the problem.
